# estimates for the largest disc not intersecting a unimodular lattice?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-lattices

Are there any nice estimates for the size of the largest disc (centered anywhere) not intersecting a unimodular (i.e. covolume = 1) lattice in the plane?  Maybe estimates in terms of the shortest nonzero vector in the lattice.  I know absolutely nothing about the geometry of numbers, so please forgive my naivete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

called covering radius. not dependent on unimodularity. If any full-dimensional ball of radius $r$ contains a lattice point, then the union of balls of radius $r$ centered at all lattice points contains all points of the vector space

Comment: Thanks, Will.  Where would I find stuff like this?  Any book on the geometry of numbers?

Comment: SPLAG, Conway and Sloane. http://books.google.com/books/about/Sphere_Packings_Lattices_and_Groups.html?id=I05rewAACAAJ  also  http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/  Note that Magma calculates the square of the covering radius, which is then rational, you need to be aware of usage as far as "even" and "odd" lattices, and so on. Also, second or third edition of Ebeling, Lattices and Codes, i found very helpful.